# Java - execute commands line by line in the same shell

Tags: java, powershell, talend

I'm new to java with Talend Open Studio.
I would like to know if it is possible to execute powershell.exe with "Import-Module ActiveDirectory", and then to launch dynamics commands without reloading powershell with "Import-Module ...".

I know this will not work, but my idea could be translated like this :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().Exec("powershell.exe");
Runtime.getRuntime().Exec("Import-Module ActiveDirectory");
Runtime.getRuntime().Exec("Get-ADUser TestLogin1");
Runtime.getRuntime().Exec("Set-ADUser -Identity TestLogin1 -Company MyCompany1");
Runtime.getRuntime().Exec("Get-ADUser TestLogin2");
Runtime.getRuntime().Exec("Set-ADUser -Identity TestLogin2 -Company MyCompany2");
```

For this to work, I have to do ...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().Exec("powershell.exe /c Import-Module ActiveDirectory ; Get-ADUser TestLogin");
Runtime.getRuntime().Exec("powershell.exe /c Import-Module ActiveDirectory ; Set-ADUser -Identity TestLogin1 -Company MyCompany1");
Runtime.getRuntime().Exec("powershell.exe /c Import-Module ActiveDirectory ; Get-ADUser TestLogin_2");
Runtime.getRuntime().Exec("powershell.exe /c Import-Module ActiveDirectory ; Set-ADUser -Identity TestLogin2 -Company MyCompany2");
```

I don't want to go through a script file because a first update command (Set-ADUser) can have an impact on the next update command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with the jPowerShell library from profesorfalken

https://github.com/profesorfalken/jPowerShell

```
//Creates PowerShell session (we can execute several commands in the same session)
   try (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.openSession()) {
       //Execute a command in PowerShell session
       PowerShellResponse response = powerShell.executeCommand("Import-Module ActiveDirectory");

       //Get an ADUser
       PowerShellResponse response = powerShell.executeCommand("Get-ADUser TestLogin1");
       //Print results ADUser
       System.out.println("PS : " + response.getCommandOutput());
       //Set an ADUser
       PowerShellResponse response = powerShell.executeCommand("Set-ADUser -Identity TestLogin1 -Company MyCompany1");

       //Get an ADUser
       PowerShellResponse response = powerShell.executeCommand("Get-ADUser TestLogin2");
       //Print results ADUser
       System.out.println("PS : " + response.getCommandOutput());
       //Set an ADUser
       PowerShellResponse response = powerShell.executeCommand("Set-ADUser -Identity TestLogin2 -Company MyCompany2");

   } catch(PowerShellNotAvailableException ex) {
       //Handle error when PowerShell is not available in the system
       //Maybe try in another way?
   }
```